# Serve Static HTML route in React App (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a normal React app using functional components. It has its own CSS and everything works fine.

I now want to incorporate another route at `/FAQ` that serves a long static HTML file (FAQ) I have that has its own CSS and design that is already written for me. I don't want to incorporate that into the rest of the apps design structure, I just want the route to take the user to the new content it its own pre-designed style.

I have tried creating a new component for my FAQ that imports the statis HTML and CSS and then simply serves this component from  `App.tsx`.

```
const App = () => {
 return(
   <Page>
    <FAQ>
   <Page>
 )
}
```

In my `FAQ` component I have tried using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute like this to load the static HTML from the file in the `Public` folder:

```
import { FC } from "react";
import FAQContent  from "./FAQ";

const FAQ: FC = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <div 
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: FAQContent  }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default FAQ;
```

I get a TS error stating:

`Type 'FC<{}>' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2322`

Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To serve the static page, place it in your project's `public` folder. You can then link to it from a React component like so:

```
<a href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/faq.html'} target="_blank">FAQ</a>
```

(process.env.PUBLIC_URL dynamically provides the location of the public folder)

Comment: This gave me an idea to use an iframe to solve a problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For routing in react, I suggest trying react-router, it would make your project much easier!

Also, if I remember it right, you can only pass type "string" inside dangerouslySetInnerHTML, so you can create a text file and pass the file into dangerouslySetInnerHTML or you can put FAQContent (as html string) in a constant and then pass the constant inside dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: Yep im using the router. I just didnt show it. The error says Type 'FC<{}>' is not assignable to type 'string'. Instead of redering the string as HTML is seems to be trying to assign the functional component to type string.

Comment: Can you show me your FAQContent?